# How to upload a .php file to Heroku

Tags: heroku

I need to upload a .php file to my Heroku site.

How is this done using Terminal? I'm logged in vis Terminal and can see my app etc...

thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to upload a file on your Heroku app through the terminal, you need to track it and commit it with `Git`.

Install and configure the heroku toolbelt if not already done: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart

And then just create your app, start tracking your files and push them to heroku:

```
heroku create myapp
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Should be `"Initial commit"` instead of `'Initial commit'`