# Is there way to run .sql script on heroku - cleardb

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have deployed my app which use mysql to heroku, but I need to populate some data from .sql script. 
When I connect with MySql Workbench , then running all inserts takes more then 1.5 hour, but it is only 48000 inserts. Imagine I would have more inserts...
Running same amount of inserts on localhost mysql is done under 2 minutes.

Is there way to upload .sql filed somewhere on heroku/cleardb and then run it directly to speed up process?

Comment: Could you show the sql statements that you are using from the workbench?

Comment: Normal one table inserts or inserts combinated with select into many to many join table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379224/how-to-upload-a-php-file-to-heroku Check this out it might be a work around. Create the db file local and push it to you db folder using git